# FPtree on java canvas

Tags: java, swing, data-mining

How to make FP-Tree from FP Growth algorithm graphically on Java canvas ? One method i got was using graphviz but i wanted to show both the itemset tree and headerlist linked list on the same FP-Tree

Comment: What is an "FP-Tree"?  Can you link to the image of one?

Comment: @AndrewThompson http://www.csc.liv.ac.uk/~frans/KDD/Software/FPgrowth/fpGrowth.html#fp-tree

Answer (score 0):

I think that it will be hard to find a library that will exactly fit the needs for drawing a FPtree with the header table. If you are good at programming, you could use the Java2D drawing API  ( http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/2D/index.jsp ) and write your own code for drawing the FPTree.  Basically, an FPTree is a directed graph so it should not be too hard. You need to calculate the x,y position for each node and element of the header table (the difficult part) and then you just need to draw the lines between the x,y position of different nodes.